# SQL Server CLR static variables set back to null

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a CLR DLL (source code written in C#) that gets loaded into SQL Server. The initialization process is expensive so it is something I usually only want to do once. However, there are times that it could be necessary to initialize again and I don't want to have to restart SQL Server to do that. As such, I have **not** marked these static variables as read-only. My problem is that my static variables are getting reset to null in a seemingly random manner. I am pretty confident that I don't have any threading issues and none of my code sets those values to null anyway. By analyzing my log files I can only guess that SQL Server is somehow resetting the values to null (perhaps reloading the DLL at times?). Does SQL Server do this? If so, is there a way to configure it not to?

Comment: The description is almost the opposite of what a SQLCLR function or aggregate should be. A SQLCLR class runs inside SQL Server's memory space, using SQL Server's threading. It's lifecycle is controlled by SQL Server. Therefore it *shouldn't* perform expensive initialization, nor require it. It *shouldn't* have static variables at all. It *shouldn't* waste memory that could be used to cache data. In other words, you do have threading issues, but these are probably the least of your problems

Comment: Where is the code and what is it trying to do? Why would a SQLCLR assembly require any kind of initialization? It's impossible to help without the code, apart from noting that SQLCLR classes aren't meant to work this way

Comment: This code is reaching out to the key manager to export cryptographic keys. I cache the keys in memory so as to not have to reach out the key manager repeatedly (as that is the expensive process). Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post any code from this particular project.

Comment: What you describe is the job of an external application or service, not SQLCLR. Just *don't* do it this way. Use a separate service, or use SQL Server's built-in key management functionality. As for "caching", you are actually *stealing* buffer memory to hold what shouldn't be held in *SQL Server's* memory.

Comment: How and when are you initializing the value? Depending on what you have tried, there might be one or two other options to attempt. Looking at the SQL Server error log, do you see entries related to the App Domain for that DB and owner being marked for unload due to memory pressure, and then unloaded?

Comment: I initialize whenever the encrypt or decrypt routine is called and the keys are not available in memory (i.e., when the static variable containing them is null). I do see entries that state "App Domain # (name.dbo[runtime]) is marked for unload due to memory pressure".

Comment: Also, I am currently testing with only 2 256-bit keys loaded into memory and the corresponding metadata with them is pretty small (key name which is a short string and they are stored in a Dictionary object). Edit: I am actually storing a Random object with each key as well and caching that off. Does that have a big memory footprint?

Comment: @Hmmmmm Are you running into a problem due to the resetting of the variable to `null`, or are you just curious as it is a slight hit to reload it each time this happens? The other option for loading it is in a static class constructor (then you _shouldn't_ need to check each time). Also, you can use `readonly` if the variable is a Collection ;-). Doing that allows for the Assembly to be marked as `SAFE`. No, those few items don't seem like too much to cache. Finally, now that more than 1 other person is commenting, you need to use the `@name` when replying so that the person gets notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server loads and unloads CLR modules as it sees fit (under memory pressure, in case of unhandled exception, [more on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310066/1132334)). Even if you were able to figure out all related conditions and timings, this is something likely to change in future versions too.

Keeping larger amounts of data will not scale well. Write a Windows Service for that, and call it from your managed UDF via tcp (for example). If you really need in-process state, use a persistent caching mechanism instead of static variables (the database, the file system) - or anticipate that statics can go null at any time, re-initializing them whenever it happens, there is nothing wrong with this approach *per se*, apart from the scalability issue, and concurrency/synchronization.